# setting up an contact form to automatically send an email with formsubmit.co not working

Tags: angular, email, form-submit

trying to set up a contact me with formsubmit.co but it doesnt seem to be working. heres the code for my form

` Contact Me!;

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="submitForm()" #contactForm="ngForm"   
 action="https://formsubmit.co/katie.m.tantillo@gmail.com" method="POST">
  <div class="field">
    <label class="label">Name</label><br>
    <input 
        type="text" 
        size="maxlength" 
        name="name" 
        class="input" 
        [(ngModel)]="name"
        #nameInput="ngModel" 
        required>

        <div class="help is-error" *ngIf="nameInput.invalid && nameInput.touched">
            <h6>Please enter your name.</h6>
        </div>

        
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label class="label">Email</label><br>
    <input 
        type="email" 
        name="email" 
        class="input" 
        [(ngModel)]="email" 
        #emailInput="ngModel"
        required
        email>

        <div class="help is-required" *ngif="emailInput.invalid && emailInput.touched">
            
            <h6>Please enter a valid email.</h6> 
        </div>
        

  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label class="label">Your Message</label><br>
    <textarea rows="2" cols="25" name="message" name="name" class="textarea" 
  [(ngModel)]="message"></textarea>
  </div>

  <button 
    type="submit" 
    class="button"
    [disabled]="contactForm.invalid">
    <span>Send</span>
  </button>`
```

I tried adding a tool to let me have an email automatically send from my website, I was expecting an email to be sent.

edited to add: this is the live site in question https://tantilloportfolio.web.app/

edited to add

```
export class ContactComponent {
  name: string="";
  email: string="";
  message: string=""

  submitForm() {
    const message = `Thanks ${this.name}! Your message has been sent to katie.m.tantillo@gmail.com. Look for a reply to ${this.email} within 24 hours.`;

    alert(message);
  }

}
enter code here
```

Comment: When you say "doesn't seem to be working" what does this mean? Are there errors in the console? Errors in the network requests?

Comment: No errors or indication in the console that its not working, the email just doesnt show up

Comment: And where is the submitForm() code?

Comment: I added it, the submit form is just supposed to be an alert, formsubmit.co doesn't list anything about needing anything beyond the code on their site to work from the front end. I did use a different method to build the inputs and the alert so maybe they are conflicting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

action and ngSubmit cannot be used together. This is your issue.

Revert your form tag to be as shown in the documentation.

If you wish to have a pop up, move your submitForm call to:

```
 <button 
    (click)="submitForm()"
    type="submit" 
    class="button"
    [disabled]="contactForm.invalid">
    <span>Send</span>
  </button>
```